# ViewPager: how to execute code in a fragment after it has fully loaded

Tags: android, android-viewpager, lifecycle

For my Android app, I'm using a ViewPager with a FragmentCollectionAdapter.

I don't think I understand the lifecycle and operation of ViewPager. Cos there's some code I need to execute that crashes the app when you in the onCreateView (in the Fragment) because parts of the view haven't fully initialized. So I want to execute code basically once the fragment is fully loaded and put on the screen. How can I do this?

I'm using an external view in the fragment for inking with a pen called InkView. InkView has a function loadInk(List brushes) to load pen strokes into the view. Using loadInk works fine when just in a normal activity. But when trying to use it in a fragment in a viewpager, it basically says that the InkView isn't fully initiated yet. Specifically, there's an onSizeChanged function in InkView which initializes a lateinit called drawCanvas which needs to be initialized for it to work in loadInk.

I've been trying to loadInk in onCreateView in my fragment, but that causes a crash (due to drawCanvas being uninitialized).

Through debugging I can see that, when I remove loadInk from onCreateView in my fragment, InkView's onSizeChanged function is called and drawCanvas is initialized, but after the code in onCreateView is complete. (So when I try to call loadInk in onCreateView, it crashes)

I need a way to execute this code after the fragment is fully loaded and the app is running on my android device.

I tried putting it in OnResume - same result.

I tried

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
```

but this did not seem to trigger

(This is the closest thing I can find to my problem here: [Execute code right after a fragment becomes visible for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378635/execute-code-right-after-a-fragment-becomes-visible-for-the-first-time))

Sorry, I'm quite new to this so sorry if this is stupid or unclear!